# Add routing in case of missing "action" in url ({controller}/{id})

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I set up a `{controller}/{id}` routing in ASP.NET MVC 5.
What I would like to achieve: if there are no `{action}` defined, call `Index()` with `id`.

I tried thism but didn't work:

```
// Keep default routing
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// Add own routing in case of missing "action"
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Controller/Id",
    url: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I don't think you can overload those routes in this order, since ID is optional in the first one then resolution of the routes is ambiguous and will default to the one added first. e.g. it will take the id you are wanting to enter as the action name from the first route. If you want to do this you have to put the 2nd route one first. In that case though to use the default routing you will have to specify all three parameters.

Comment: If you added some constraints & reversed the order of the rules, it might work as you intend

Comment: Thanks for both of you. I tried what Simon suggested and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading ameer's comment it become clear that the routing is not that "intelligent" that I was hoping for, so if the URL pattern is matching one route, but no such controller/method found, it will not "fall through" to the next routing command, but will raise exception.

So I had tried what Simon suggested, added constraint to my custom routing, and reversed the order, and it works now. However, if I would like to have other mappings similar to attachments, I'd have to add them one by one.

Working code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Attachments",
    url: "attachments/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Attachments", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```